# The compactness of $\{x_n=cos nt\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in L_2[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, compactness

Is the set $\{x_n=\cos (nt): n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ in $L_2[-\pi,\pi]$closed or compact? I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Probably you should also say what topology you mean.  The sequence $x_n$ converges to zero in the weak topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not compact, because it is a discrete subspace of $L^2$, and there are no countable discrete compact spaces. You could also say that if it were compact, there'd be a convergent subsequence $x_{\phi(n)}$, but $x_n$ tends weakly to zero, and $0$ is not one of the $x_n$.

However, it is closed.

Comment: The easiest way to see it is closed, is to remember the fact that the $\cos(nt)$ and $\sin(nt)$ together (and properly renormalised) form a Hilbert basis for $L^2$. From there on it is rather straightforward.

Comment: Easier still: since it is discrete, it has no limit points, so vacuously it contains all its limit points, hence is closed.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't understand your comment, are you saying it is a closed subspace because it is discrete? That's not true, so what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I misused the word "discrete".  What I meant was that it has no limit points, because as in Davide's answer, no pair of points is closer than distance 2.

Answer (score 4):

As the elements are orthogonal, we have for $n\neq m$ that 
$$\lVert x_n-x_m\rVert_{L^2}^2=2,$$
proving that the set cannot be compact (it's not precompact, as the definition doesn't work for $\varepsilon=1/2$).

But it's a closed set, as it's the orthogonal of the even square-integrable functions.